Writing queries and tables in different drift files
I am trying to set up a local database with the drift package, and would prefer to write both table declarations and queries in drift files to keep it SQL and separate from other files. However, I keep getting errors that the table in my query can't be found in any import, because the table is defined in the g.dart file which can't be imported (got an error when I tried that). Is it even possible to do this? Or must I simply accept that my queries will have to be written in dart?
Additionally, the AuthDao class throws an error that it couldn't read the tables from the @DriftAccessor annotation, even though I import the local_database.dart file and it doesn't throw any error in the editor. I'm a bit lost on the structure of the interaction between drift and dart!
-- create_tables.drift
----- TABLE DEFINITIONS -----
-- User table
CREATE TABLE Users (
                    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, 
                    created_at TEXT NOT NULL,
                    first_name TEXT NOT NULL, 
                    last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
                    user_name TEXT NOT NULL,
                    email_address TEXT NOT NULL,
                    city TEXT,
                    country TEXT,
                    dob TEXT,
                    gender TEXT,
                    bio TEXT,
                    privacy TEXT DEFAULT("Friends")
);

// local_database.dart
import 'package:myapp/global/services/auth_queries.dart';
import 'package:drift/drift.dart';
import 'package:drift_flutter/drift_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

part 'local_database.g.dart';

@DriftDatabase(include: {'create_tables.drift'}, daos: [AuthDao])
class LocalDatabase extends _$LocalDatabase {
  LocalDatabase() : super(_openConnection());

  @override
  int get schemaVersion => 1;

  static QueryExecutor _openConnection() {
    return driftDatabase(name: 'local_db');
  }
}

-- local_queries.drift
import 'package:myapp/global/services/local_database.dart';

saveUser: INSERT INTO Users (id, created_at, first_name, last_name, user_name, email_address) VALUES (:id, :created_at, :first_name, :last_name, :user_name, :email_address);

// auth_queries.dart
import 'package:myapp/global/services/local_database.dart';
import 'package:drift/drift.dart';

part 'auth_queries.g.dart';

@DriftAccessor(include: {'local_auth_queries.drift'}, tables: [Users])
class AuthDao extends DatabaseAccessor<LocalDatabase> with _$AuthDaoMixin {
  AuthDao(LocalDatabase db) : super(db);

  // Future<List<dynamic>> getUsers() async {
  //   return await select(users).get();
  // }
}

